# Are there any examples of functions that take inputs of different types (for example number, String) and produce output?

Tags: computer-science

In programming it is rather the norm than the exception to have functions whose input are different data types. For example a function who produces a substring of a given string would have the following signature in Java:

public static String substring(String s, int n) {..}

Are there examples of such functions in Mathematics and what is their application?

Comment: any time someone talks about the size of a vector or the number of columns of a matrix they are really calling something like `public int length(double[] v)` or `public int n_cols(double[][] A)`, if you want to think of it that way :)

Comment: The definite integral can be considered a function which requires a real-valued function and two real numbers, and produces a real number.

Comment: The external product in a vector space : $\mathbb{R} \times V \to V$, input $(\lambda, v)$ ; output $\lambda v$

Comment: In the same vein as @Matthew Leingang : the evaluation of a function $f$ at a point $a$ : input $(f,a)$ ; output the real number $f(a)$.

Comment: Just as computers encode all those data types in binary, you can encode a lot in an integer if you allow the integer to be large enough. Consider Gödel's incompleteness theorems.